# How can you just copy an answer posted by another user and mark the copy as accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, etiquette

[retrieve value inside certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736133/retrieve-value-inside-certain-pattern)

I don't know why the person who asked the question is allowed to do this.

Comment: Offending answer has been deleted (not by me).

Comment: Well, that's odd. My initial thought was "new user who doesn't understand how SO works," but this guy has other posts. I wonder why this happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I don't think it is very strictly forbidden, but I agree with you that this is not how SO is meant to function. If it isn't strictly forbidden, it actually should be. You can off course downvote the answer, and point out to the OP that this is not acceptable practice.

You can always flag the answer for moderator attention (see the little links bottom left of the post).

Comment: Thanks Joris, Just found out I don't have enough reputation points to do the downvote at the moment....

Comment: @Bolu I've downvoted it since its a straight copy and paste. Some mod will probably come along soon and delete it

Comment: @Bolu : my downvote is added to it too.